# CGAL 2.5D mesh with minimum element area

Tags: c++, cgal

I'm trying to build a 2.5D mesh from a LIDAR dataset **A** consisting of ~50,000,000 points *(x,y,z)* to describe the terrain in an urban area. The final aim is to use this mesh for numerical simulation of flooding and I'm having trouble with too small elements. I took the following steps:

- use Point_Processing_3 to create a reduced set **B** of points *(x,y,z)* retaining about 1% of the original data ( `CGAL::wlop_simplify_and_regularize_point_set`)
- create a constrained Delaunay triangulation *cdt* using simplified building footprints as constraints (`CGAL::Constrained_Delaunay_triangulation_2`)
- insert the points from **B** into *cdt* if they are located at least 1m from any existing vertex in the triangulation
- refine the mesh using Delaunay_mesher_2

  ```
  #include <CGAL/Delaunay_mesher_2.h>
  #include <CGAL/Delaunay_mesh_size_criteria_2.h>
  Meshing_engine engine(cdt);
  engine.refine_mesh();
  ```

So far so good. The resulting mesh looks very nice. However, I end up with quite a lot of very small triangles which will make any hydraulic simulation very difficult. I have no idea how to get rid of these.

The criteria used in combination with `refine_mesh()` seem to always aim at penalizing large elements, while this is the opposite case. In many areas large triangles will be perfectly fine, but triangles with a size of 0.5sqm should never occur.

Another option would be to manually remove vertices from the triangulation using `cdt.remove(vertex_handle)`. But, given a too small face, how to pick the vertex to remove?

Can anyone help pointing in a direction? I attached an image where one of the problematic areas is marked red.

[2.5D mesh with problem areas marked red. Empty areas are buildings.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cj420.jpg)

Comment: For the circled region, my guess is that you have many points on the boundary which when you do the conforming Delaunay step adds a lot of points. Maybe you can simplify the contours using [2D Polyline Simplification](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polyline_simplification_2/index.html#Chapter_2D_Polyline_simplification). Also, is the CDT not sufficient for your simulation? Maybe a few [Lloyd iterations](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_2/index.html#title9) might help.

Comment: I simplified the boundaries before adding them as constraints into the triangulation so each building is represented by only a few vertices. However, the meshing process then creates new points along the constraints. 
I have for now moved to not using the buildings as constraints at all, and simply add them as points with a high z value into the triangulation instead. I will test your suggestion of simply using the CDT in combination with Lloyd and get back. Thanks

Comment: Following @sloriot 's comment: Seems like LLoyd is actually difficult to use in combination with `CGAL/Projection_traits_xy_3.h`.  
I'm using

`typedef CGAL::Projection_traits_xy_3<K>  Gt;  
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_2<Gt> Vb1;  
typedef CGAL::Delaunay_mesh_vertex_base_2<Gt,Vb1> Vb;  
...  
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<Vb, Fb> Tds;  
typedef CGAL::Constrained_Delaunay_triangulation_2<Gt, Tds> cdt;`

resulting in `'area' : is not a member of 'CGAL::Triangle_3<R_>'`

Comment: Should be fixed by [this PR](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/pull/697)